# Where does "::value" get its value?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

I've been reading up about SFINAE and see some examples with some variant of the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Ts> using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_typedef_foobar : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_typedef_foobar<T, void_t<typename T::foobar>> : std::true_type {};

struct foo {
  using foobar = float;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << has_typedef_foobar<int>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << has_typedef_foobar<foo>::value << std::endl;
}
```

(Taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)

I'm confused as to where the `value` member comes from.  Both definitions of has_typedef_foobar don't seem to specify a boolean member named value.

Where does `::value` get its value?  I suspect it's some kind of compiler-provided value and would like to read up about it, but I'm not sure what term to google since my queries have brought up other C++11-related value-related topics.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::true_type` and `std::false_type` are defined as:

```
using true_type = std::integral_constant<bool, true>
using false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>
```

respectively. That is, they're two separate instantiations of `std::integral_constant`.

Now if you look at a possible implementation of `std::integeral_constant`:

```
template<class T, T v>
struct integral_constant {
  ...
  static constexpr T value = v;
  ...
};
```

Among other things you'll see a `static constexpr` variable named `value`. Naturally, if you instantiate `std::integeral_constant` as `std::integral_constant<bool, true>` then `value` member variable in the instatiatation is set to `true`. In the same manner, if you instantiate `std::integral_constant` as `std::integral_constant<bool, false>` then its `value` member variable is set to `false`.

Inheriting from `std::true_type` you also inherit the `value` member variable that is set to `true` and inheriting from `std::false_type` type you also inherit the `value` member variable that is set to `false`.

Comment: Thanks.  It didn't immediately connect in my mind to look up `std::true_type`, as I had been thinking it was some syntax of `struct` of which I wasn't aware.